# jQuery LazyLoad with Smarty template

Tags: jquery, smarty, lazy-loading

I use Smarty 2 at my website and I would like to use jQuery LazyLoad also.

I use html_thumb to generate thumbinail, how can I adapt this

```
{html_thumb 
      src=$appconfig.image.product.app.path|cat:$item.id|cat:$smarty.const.DS|cat:$item.NAME_OF_PICTURE_IN_BASE 
      error_image_path=$appconfig.image.product.thumb.web.error 
      save_path=$appconfig.image.product.thumb.app.path|cat:$item.id|cat:$smarty.const.DS 
      display_path=$appconfig.image.product.thumb.web.path|cat:$item.id|cat:"/" 
      alt=$item.name 
      w=119 
      h=102 
      zc=0 
      far=1 
      bgcolor='FFFFFF' 
      q=100}
```

To use LazyLoad, example:

```
<img data-original="img/example.jpg" src="img/grey.gif" width="640" height="480">
```

Thank you.

Comment: `{html_thumb src='img/grey.gif' data-original=$appconfig.image.product.app.path|cat:$item.id|cat:$smarty.const.DS|cat:$item.NAME_OF_PICTURE_IN_BASE ...}`

Comment: I wish that could be so easy. Your solution don't work, obviously. Is there anybody that could help me?

Comment: Could you please be more specific with "don't work" ?

Comment: I want to use this for products list in categories and your solution causes that list of the products don't show. It's because "src" in original is just showing the path to big size pictures and based on that path, thumbnail is generated. And with your solution html_thumb can't get file path. I also tried to switch data-original with display_path which is more obvious but it doesn't work either. Any suggestions?